# Git lost track of the fact that I was merging

Tags: git

I just completed a very difficult merge, but some time during the merge I did something that caused git to loose track of the fact that I was merging (I probably did `git reset` or something).

Now all the files I have locally are correctly merged, but I can't finish the merge since git doesn't know I'm merging. Any idea how to get out of this problem? The merge took a really long time, so I don't want to manually do it again. Basically I want to keep the local state exactly as it is, but just inform git that it should create a merge commit (from the current branch and a specific other branch) instead of a regular commit.

Comment: Do all files in the current commit have the content they should have?

Comment: There wasn't a commit yet, just some staged and some unstaged changes as I'd been resolving merge conflicts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git looks for a [reference](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefrefaref) called `MERGE_HEAD`<sup>1</sup> to determine whether the next commit should be a merge commit. This reference should point to the tip of the branch to merge into the current one (i.e the *target* branch).

In your case, you can just create the `MERGE_HEAD` yourself by using the [`update-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-ref) command:

```
git update-ref MERGE_HEAD $(git rev-parse <target-branch>)
git merge --continue
```

`MERGE_HEAD` is automatically deleted at the end of a merge operation, whether it was completed or aborted.

---

<sup>1</sup> Which is nothing more than a [text file](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) in the `.git` directory, really.